# How to overlay basis functions onto GAM plot

Tags: regression, spline, gam, mgcv, gratia

I am trying to find a way to replicate a plot similar to this, where the splines and the basis functions that make up those splines are both plotted in the same window.

[image]

I have successfully done both separately below:

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(mgcv)
library(tidyverse)
library(gratia)
library(gamair)
library(ggpubr)

#### Set Theme ####
theme_set(theme_bw())

#### Add Data ####
data("wesdr")
wes <- as_tibble(wesdr)
wes

#### Fit GAM ####
fit <- gam(
  ret ~ s(dur, bs = "cr"),
  method = "REML",
  family = binomial,
  data = wes
)

#### Plot Basis Functions ####
b <- draw(basis(fit))
s <- draw(fit)
ggarrange(b,s)
```

[image]

However, I'm not sure how to mash them together. Simply throwing them on top of each other obviously doesn't work:

```
#### Attempt at Plotting BF and Spline ####
wes %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=dur,
             y=ret))+
  stat_smooth(method = "gam",
              method.args = list(family = binomial),
              formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cr"),
              se = T,
              color = "steelblue")+
  geom_line(data = basis(fit),
            aes(x=dur,
                y=value,
                color=bf))
```

[image]

How can one achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The figure isn't really showing or using any response data, only values of the spline covariate and it doesn't really need that unless you want pretty, smooth, basis functions. It's a different matter if you want to draw the basis for an estimated spline. Assuming you might want both (the first for teaching or explaining how splines work, the second to explain it in terms of a specific fit), below I show how to generate both kinds of figure.

#### option 1, using a basis and user-specified weights

```r
library("mgcv")
library("gratia")
library("dplyr")

df <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 1, length = 100))
bs <- basis(s(x, bs = "bs", k = 10), data = df)

# let's weight the basis functions (simulating model coefs)
set.seed(1)
betas <- data.frame(bf = factor(1:10), beta = rnorm(10))

# we need to merge the weights for each basis function with the basis object
bs <- bs |>
    left_join(betas, by = join_by("bf" == "bf")) |>
    mutate(value_w = value * beta)

# now we want to sum the weighted basis functions for each value of `x`
spl <- bs |>
    group_by(x) |>
    summarise(spline = sum(value_w))

# now plot
bs |> 
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = value_w, colour = bf, group = bf)) +
    geom_line(show.legend = FALSE) +
    geom_line(aes(x = x, y = spline), data = spl, linewidth = 1.5,
              inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    labs(y = expression(f(x)), x = "x")
```

This produces:

[image]

#### option 2, using an estimated model

If you want to do this for an actual model fit, you could follow the above example, but you would need to include the identifiability constraints in the spline (see `?basis`) and extract the correct weights for the basis functions from the vector of model coefficients returned by `coef(m)`.

{gratia}'s `basis()` has a method for fitted models, which automates this process.

```r
dat <- data_sim("eg1", seed = 4)
m <- gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2, bs = "bs") + s(x3),
         data = dat, method = "REML")

# data to evaluate the basis at
# using the CRAN version of {gratia}, we need `m`
ds <- data_slice(m, x2 = evenly(x2, n = 200))
# from 0.9.0 (or current GitHub version) you can do
# ds <- data_slice(dat, x2 = evenly(x2, n = 200))

# generate a tidy representation of the fitted basis functions
x2_bs <- basis(m, term = "s(x2)", data = ds)

# compute values of the spline by summing basis functions at each x2
x2_spl <- x2_bs |>
    group_by(x2) |>
    summarise(spline = sum(value))

# now plot
x2_bs |> 
    ggplot(aes(x = x2, y = value, colour = bf, group = bf)) +
    geom_line(show.legend = FALSE) +
    geom_line(aes(x = x2, y = spline), data = x2_spl, linewidth = 1.5,
              inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    labs(y = expression(f(x2)), x = "x2")
```

This produces

[image]

To get the final version you wanted (with a credible interval), evaluate the spline at the same covariate values using `smooth_estimates()` instead of manually summing the basis functions:

```r
# evaluate the spline at the same values as we evaluated the basis functions
x2_sm <- smooth_estimates(m, "s(x2)", data = ds) |>
    add_confint()

# now plot
x2_bs |> 
    ggplot(aes(x = x2, y = value, colour = bf, group = bf)) +
    geom_line(show.legend = FALSE) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(x = x2, ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci),
                data = x2_sm, # <---- new !
                inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line(aes(x = x2, y = est), data = x2_sm, # <---- new !
              linewidth = 1.5, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    labs(y = expression(f(x2)), x = "x2")
```

which produces

[image]

##### Where were you going wrong?

I think your approach didn't work for a couple of reasons.

1. `draw()` methods don't return the underlying data. By design (because of how `ggplot()` works) they return ggplot objects. It is better to use functions (like you did with `basis()`) to get the outputs you want, and then plot them yourself using `ggplot()`, as I showed with the last example in Option 2.
2. Don't ever use `geom_smooth()` or `stat_smooth()` to fit a GAM. It's easy to make mistakes; here you forget to ask for `method = "REML"`, which you need to do through `method_args = list(method = "REML")` in the `stat_smooth()` call.

You approach isn't too wrong though; notice that many of the basis functions on the left of the figure are negative so they pull the fitted spline down, even though some of the other basis functions peak above the fitted spline.

One final comment; use the {patchwork} package to arrange objects returns by `draw()` as you'll get better alignment.

```r
library("patchwork")
b + s + plot_layout(ncol = 2)
```

`draw.gam()` and many other `draw()` methods in {gratia} already return patchworks, not simple ggplot objects, so you'll get the best compatibility if you use {patchwork}'s layout tools.

Comment: +1 for your super detailed answer. Just a quick thing: not sure what the issue is, but it appears the `data_slice` function doesn't work for your data or the data I tried it on for my use case. It gives me the error: `Error: Don't know how to create a data slice from <tbl_df>`. I was able to run through Option 1 without issues, but I need to find another way for Option 2 it seems.

Comment: Ah I figured it out. Where you have `dat` I think it should be `m`. I edited that and it worked right away. Thanks a bunch as always!

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Sorry; the data frame method for `data_slice()` is only in the development version on GitHub and as I'm getting close to releasing it to CRAN I have been using it as my daily driver. If you install the version from GitHub, the code will work as is

Comment: Thanks I look forward to the new release.